# stylesheet for css not being implemented for next.js components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, next.js

I have the React/Next component below. I am trying to use a stylesheet to make it look better but for some reason the css is not being applied.

What do I do to fix this? I tried calling the stylesheet in pages/index.js and/or pages/_app.js but nothing changed.

Comment: it seemed correct to me, do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how CSS Modules works.

Try this:

```
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.css';
...
const LoginUser = ({onChangeLoginForm, loginUser}) => {

    return(      
        <div className={styles.container}>
...
```

Comment: Also, usually, we use [ComponentName].module.css, so in your example, the name is better to be LoginUser.module.css

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake on your code. `<p>` tag has align attribute which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the docs for css modules: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css

Adjust your import:

```
import styles from '../../styles/ComponentName.module.css'
```

Then use use it like:

```
<div class={styles.classname}/>
```